# Vim Log Events (Close Window)

Tags: events, vim

For my current problem I need some kind of `WinClose` event in *Vim*. I know that there is the `WinNew` event thrown when I split a window. The same I need for the `:close` command. In the list of events (`:h autocmd-events`) I couldn't find something like this reading the descriptions. Also if other pairs like `TabNew` & `TabClosed` or `WinEnter` & `WinLeave` are there.
So the idea is to track all events thrown in *Vim* and try to find out what event is thrown when closing a window like this.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Create a log file with `vim -V20logfile.log test.txt`. In test.txt you can trigger some auto commands, for example split window then close window. Quit Vim and open logfile.log. Then search for test.txt. There will be lines like `Executing BufWinEnter Auto commands for "*"` that indicate what auto commands are executed. To create a log file with only auto command information you could use this code: https://gist.github.com/nobe4/aa8313fe98ca8821afad

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7170

Answer (score 0):

[vim v8.2.3591](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/23beefed73aadb243fb67cf944e3d60fe8c038bb) added a WinClosed event.